# Classification using LibSVM

Tags: c, opencv, libsvm

I am using LibSVM to carry out some multi-class classifications. I trained the model using the MATLAB interface of LibSVM. I then saved this model in a format that would be recognized in C. I now want to classify using svm_predict in C. I am having trouble being able to reproduce the results that I saw in MATLAB. In fact I get the same class output irrespective of what test vector I feed in (even a vector of zeros) I think the issue is with the way I am loading the test vector x into the svm_node structure. Below is the code snippet. Do let me know if this is correct way or if I am missing something.

```
struct svm_model *libsvm_model = svm_load_model('mymodel.svm');
struct svm_node x[2001]; // this is for one feature vector of size 2000x1
int index = 1;
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < features.size(); i++) {
  x[i].index = index;
  x[i].value = features.at(i); 
  index = index + 1; 
}

x[i+1].index = -1;
x[i+1].value = '?';

double result = svm_predict(libsvm_model, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem:

```
x[i+1].index = -1;
x[i+1].value = '?';
```

`libsvm` requires `svm_node` to be an **input** vector, which should have positive indexes, and double values. You should not "leave" some weird empty dimension.

And by the way, you don't need `index` variable

```
for (i = 0; i < features.size(); i++) {
  x[i].index = index;
  x[i].value = features.at(i); 
  index = index + 1; 
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (i = 0; i < features.size(); i++) {
  x[i].index = i + 1;
  x[i].value = features.at(i);  
}
```